# Creating a list of users using scope based on join table in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am moving my user roles from a boolean associated with the user (e.g. `user.teacher = true`) to a join table style where there are two models: `user` and `role`, connected by a join table `user_roles`. I used to get all my administrators with `scope :admins, -> { where(admin: true) }`, but that doesn't work anymore (a lot of my tests are failing!). How would I get admins when the roles are now stored in another table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a join to restrict to users with a specific role. I'm going to assume your `Role` model has a `name` attribute. The join looks like this:

```
User.joins(:roles).where(roles: { name: "Admin" })
```

You could wrap that up in a scope, maybe with a helper if you'll be adding more roles in the future:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :with_role, -> (n) { joins(:roles).where(roles: { name: n })) }
  scope :admins, -> { with_role("Admin") }
end
```

You could also add an instance method like this:

```
def has_role?(role_name)
  roles.find_by(name: role_name).present?
end
```

Comment: I had tried a joins, but it looks like I didn't do it right. Would the best way to then check if a user has a role (i.e. checking if the user id and specific role id is a row in the join table) be `def has_role?(role) User.joins(:roles).where(roles: { name: role }).include?(self) end` ?

Comment: @mjswartz I wouldn't do it like that. In instance variables, unlike scopes, you traverse the associations directly. Will add an example